# Should I use Eclipse wizard to deploy web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, deployment

I use Eclipse "**Dynamic Web Project**" to create and test web application. It will publish my application on application server in convenient way. I don't need to write script, just wizard.

However, I am wondering it is a decent way to deploy a web application. What's your opinion? Thanks!

(I used to use Ant script to deploy my application, it's standard way.)

plus: Dynamic Web Project uses its specific directory layout which is different with Maven standard directory layout.

Answer (score 4):

This is fine for deploying to a dev or test server. Its a convenient way to quickly deploy to have a look at changes you've made and to do tests.

I would definitely **not** allow this for any other environment, eg live, pre-production etc. You should have an established process (eg documented change control) to deploy to these environments.

Comment: Do you mean Ant or Maven must be used in deployment yet？

Comment: I think Qwerky mean the policy of deployment process. Let say some guy changed the app so it doesn't work or has unexpected behavior

Answer (score 1):

I have heard it's still recommended to cold deploy and restart the server for not having a trouble with memory leaks, dynamic class loaders. For myself I think comfortable to deploy from Eclipse to most environments. Basically Eclipse WTP server adapter can run the same deploy command as the other processes. When I use clouds like GAE or Beanstalk I do deploy from Eclipse plugin, it is the same like command line.